# Camera.ScreenPointToRay not doing anything

Tags: c#, input, unity-game-engine

I have the following code,

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Catch : MonoBehaviour {
    public float distance;
    GameObject exterminator;
    GameObject exterminatorCameraObject;
    Camera exterminatorCamera;
    public bool isCarryingPickupableObject = false;
    public bool stepone, steptwo, stepthree,stepfour;
    GameObject carriedObject;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        stepone = steptwo = stepthree = stepfour= false;
        exterminator = GameObject.FindWithTag("Exterminator");
        exterminatorCameraObject = GameObject.FindWithTag("ExterminatorCamera");
        exterminatorCamera = exterminatorCamera.GetComponent<Camera>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (isCarryingPickupableObject)
        {
            carry(carriedObject);
            checkDrop();
        }
        else
        {
            pickup();
        }

    }
    void carry(GameObject o)
    {
        o.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
        o.GetComponent<Transform>().position = exterminatorCameraObject.transform.position + exterminatorCameraObject.transform.forward * distance;

    }
    void pickup()
    {
        stepone = true;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
        {
            steptwo=true;
            //Determine middle of screen for pickup/catch raycast.
            int x = Screen.width / 2;
            int y = Screen.height / 2;
            Ray ray = exterminatorCamera.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(x, y));
            RaycastHit hit;
            stepthree = true;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit))
            {
                stepfour = true;
                Pickupable p = hit.collider.GetComponent<Pickupable>();
                if (p != null)
                { 
                    isCarryingPickupableObject = true;
                    carriedObject = p.gameObject;
                    p.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void checkDrop()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
        {
            dropObject();
        }
    }
    void dropObject()
    {
        isCarryingPickupableObject = false;
        carriedObject.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
        carriedObject = null;

    }
}
```

However in my `pickup` function, my `GetKeyDown` call never happens?

Why would this be? (Booleans never change that I am using to watch this with).

As a note: `stepone` becomes true, but none of the other steps do.

EDIT:

I made another step, it appears it makes it to `steptwo` but no further...

EDIT: It appears the `ScreenPointToRay` isn't doing anything...?

Comment: is `exterminatorCameraObject` null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things i can point out:

1. You declare a `Vector3`, and you only give it an `x` and a `y`
2. Even though you can pass a `Vector2` into `ScreenPointToRay(...)`, i highly recommend using a `Vector3`, as
   the function uses `z` for distance from camera, and inferring a `z`
   of `0f` distance makes it pretty hard to infer your `Ray`
3. Try using `camera.pixelWidth` and `pixelHeight`, as `Screen.width` and `height` coordinates may not necessarily exist
   within the camera's view.

So heres what i would try:

```
int distance = 100f;
int x = exterminatorCamera.pixelWidth / 2;
int y = exterminatorCamera.pixelHeight / 2;
Ray ray = exterminatorCamera.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(x, y, distance));
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking your [console log](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Console.html) for errors. If you are making it to 'steptwo', the only way you would not make it to 'stepthree' is if there was an error.

I tried your code and by assigning my own Camera I was able to get to 'stepthree' so I have to assume it isn't getting your camera and a null reference error is stopping your script from getting that far.

[Debug.Log](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html) is your friend. Try inserting a Debug.Log(exterminatorCamera) to see if the camera is being assigned. You can also use [Debug.DrawRay](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html) to see the ray being output by the ScreenPointToRay function.